# Skype starts on boot, ignoring the option setting

Tags: windows-7, boot, skype

For the last two days, Skype has been starting when I boot my computer. This is happening on both of my computers (both of which are Windows 7). Up until that point, Skype did not display this behavior. I checked to see that an update hadn't changed my settings, but the option to start with windows was still unchecked. I also went into msconfig and verified that it wasn't in the startup tab. What else could be causing it to start up on boot?

Comment: There are many other places to check. See [Windows Program Automatic Startup Locations](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-program-automatic-startup-locations/)

Comment: No luck finding it in those locations. I also ran hijackthis, which showed the skype updater as an automatic service. That is the only culprit I can think of right now.

Comment: Try stopping the service and set it to manual.